# Modernizing Struts 1.x Application

Tags: spring-mvc, struts-1, legacy

I would like to modernize my Struts 1.x application. There are quite a number of articles which advocate migration of codes, instead of rewriting the entire system.

I would like to seek the advice of someone who has successfully modernize legacy applications.

My current system is using struts 1.x and JDBC prepared statements as the data access layer.

I am looking forward to improve the legacy application with the following objectives:

1. Web Pages should be coded with Responsive Web Design in mind.
2. Replace struts 1.x with Spring MVC

I am looking to breaking up the modernization into the following phases:

1. Phase 1 - Change all jsp pages to HTML 5 and CSS 3
2. Phase 2 - Change all DAO classes to Spring JDBC Template or Spring JPA
   and transactions managed by Spring
3. Phase 3 - Ultimately, replace Struts 1.x Action Forms, Actions with Spring MVC

Before I start the changes, I would like to find out if it is possible for:

1. Struts 1.x with HTML 5 and CSS 3? I am looking at replacing all struts 1.x html taglibs with HTML 5 and JSTL/EL.
2. Running Struts 1.x with Spring 3/4? Is it possible to run non-spring managed pojo with Spring beans?

What should I take note of and how/what are the best practices to handle this modernization process? The code base is about 500k of HTML/JSP codes and 3 million Java codes.

Comment: phase 2 and 3: you will need to "inject" the Spring @Service classes (which use JDBC template or JPA) inside Struts actions, which can be done if you get a handle on Spring application context from within Struts actions. For this purpose you define a Spring "context aware" bean which sets some static field, e.g. myApplicationContext, to the application context as in the link  http://sujitpal.blogspot.it/2007/03/accessing-spring-beans-from-legacy-code.html . Then you simply access the static field of this class to get the application context and the services. So it seems you can do it that way.

Comment: Which means I can't use annotation at all for Struts 1.x with Spring?

Comment: Well, at first you use annotations (e.g. JPA) for the services. (phase 2). Then, during phase 3, when you convert the actions to Spring MVC, you will use the Spring MVC annotations.

Comment: yes, the correct way to retrieve the application context would be the one indicated in the answer by @JavierCaselli, not the link in my comment.

Comment: and as @JavierCaselli says, keeping Struts 1.x running alongside Spring is a bad idea. After phase 3, you probably should not have Struts 1.x in your application any more.

Comment: I can still use annotation to register my Component, Repository and Service class, but I have to retrieve the Spring managed beans from application context for non Spring managed beans? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, definitely not running Strut 1.x with Spring MVC

Comment: "but I have to retrieve the Spring managed beans from application context for non Spring managed beans? Am I right?" - yes.

Comment: "After phase 3, you probably should not have Struts 1.x in your application any more" - it should be possible to reuse the tiles, however.

Comment: I wonder about the downvotes to this question. Care to explain?

Comment: yes, I wonder what are the down votes for.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: I beg to differ. This can be a systematic process to perform the upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's been a while since I last worked with Struts 1.x, but I see no problem replacing at least most of the Struts tags with JSTL/EL. You should be able to paint HTML5 with Struts 1.x JSPs. I remember working using little or no Struts tags, only JSTL/EL, but this was before HTML5.
2. You can invoke Spring Context from any Struts ActionForm or, essentially any class within your webapp. You'll probably have to do it manually though and not with annotations, something like this:

   WebApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());

With all this said, I can see you're intending to do a serious update of your app, therefore I must ask, are you positive about keeping Struts 1.x? If you want to ditch Struts tags, use Spring 3/4 and HTML 5, why not dispense with Struts entirely and migrate your app to Spring MVC? It's very easy to use, powerful and, needless to say, it integrates perfectly with the Spring components implementing your business logic, persistence, etc.

Cheers.

Comment: From the management or user perspectives, it doesn't matter to them what frameworks the application is running on, most importantly the system is running fine. I am looking at a step by step approach to mitigate any project failure or risk

Comment: I am breaking up the phases to minimize the risks involved.

Comment: @youcanlearnanything "I am looking at a step by step approach to mitigate any project failure or risk" if your application does not use javascript very much, you could try to create a full suite of Selenium tests for your current application (when the application is not javascript intensive, this is not very difficult or time consuming . once you get over the initial threshlod), and then test your reengineered application against this suite. And of course it is better to create unit tests to test that JPA queries give the same results as the original SQL queries used.

Comment: Sadly to say, my application uses a lot of JavaScript. Pondering if there is any benefits converting these JavaScript to jQuery or AngularJS as well?

Comment: @youcanlearnanything jQuery - maybe, AngularJS definitely not, in my opinion, since it seems to me that it really changes the application structure. With jQuery you will have simple ajax and nice tables/UI components. But by replacing your original javascript with jQuery, it seems to me that it is hard to know whether the original functionality is kept and did not become broken.  Perhaps phase 4?

Comment: JQuery is very powerful and delivers relatively clean code (we are talking JS here), It wouldn't hurt to import it into your template and test in on a few relatively simple views of your app so that you can ponder it it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

(Not an answer, informational.)

1. There's no reason you can't have an S1 app running alongside Spring MVC. It's a reasonable way to migrate piece-by-piece instead of a longer project that does a complete replacement.
2. Older Spring has direct support for Struts 1. Depending on your timeframe I might consider using the older Spring until you're further along.
3. Replacing S1 tags with pure HTML/CSS will be a pain because the S1 tags render other stuff besides just the input fields (e.g., labels, error messages, etc.) It's totally doable, especially if you write your own custom tags.
4. jQuery v. (AngularJS | React | similar) Switching to a full-on client-side app is a big lift, especially if your back-end isn't already designed that way. I wouldn't do that, but you could get a start on it by putting business logic in its own place and using that from the web layer. Then...
5. ... you start to consume API calls on the client side using jQ or other client-side framework injected into the existing pages. Only then would I start considering going full SPA.

The bottom line is you have a fairly large app. Rather than converting the entire thing I would consider removing functionality from the mainline app and break it up into sub-applications, each of which could use whatever tech stack seems reasonable.

I've done a lot of project like this as a consultant: it's a lot of busywork that requires a wide range of knowledge and skills, and it's difficult to get right.

Comment: You mean that in a single web application (war file), I can have both struts 1.x and spring mvc residing in it? i.e Within the war file, I am running Module A on struts 1.x and Module B on spring mvc?

Comment: Sure, no reason why not. Moving between them can be a bit of a headache since you'd generally want to either use separate extensions or namespaces, but that's the only major issue.

Comment: "Older Spring has direct support for Struts 1" - I wonder if there is any sense in using older Spring (I think 2.5?), since then you would have to upgrade in some stage to Spring 4+ anyway, and at least in my opinion it is better to upgrade immediately to Spring 4.

Comment: @JohnDonn Hard to say. The lack of direct support isn't insurmountable, but it's a learning curve either way. I'd favor breaking it up into smaller applications, which is likely possible given its size.

Comment: I ported the struts1 support to spring5, so it's possible to start with upgrading spring: https://blog.hackeriet.no/integration-between-struts-1.3-and-spring-5.0/